# Databases on multiple servers for write and in a single server for read

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a database with single table busy_table1 in a server say  server_1.
Another database with single table busy_table2 in a server say  server_2.
Those databases are just for writing and would like  to use aws aurora.
Is it possible to use read servers with two databases in the same server?

My goal is for write I would like to use databases in different  servers, but for reading all those databases should be in same server. And I should be able to scale the read server and should be able to use aurora.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What's you are looking for is Aurora Multi Master. You may want to try out the preview.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/sign-up-for-the-preview-of-amazon-aurora-multi-master/

You could try out your databases against a single master as well, as long as you choose one of the biggest instance types. For example, an 8XL or 16XL is large enough that you may actually not need to share your writes into two servers. Would highly encourage profiling single master as well.